# getTheme() native base Type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, native-base

I'm using a custom `Native Base` style theme as described in this link.

https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#theaming-nb-headref
Imports:

```
import material from './native-base-theme/variables/material';
import getTheme from './native-base-theme/components';
```

```
return (
    <Suspense fallback="loading">
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StyleProvider style={getTheme(material)}>
```

Inside getTheme(), on `material`, I get this TypeScript error:

> Argument of type '{ platformStyle: string; platform: "ios" | "android"
> | "windows" | "macos" | "web"; headerStyle: string; iconStyle: string;
> contentStyle: string; expandedIconStyle: string; accordionBorderColor:
> string; ... 151 more ...; Inset: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '{ platformStyle: any; platform: "ios" | "android" |
> "windows" | "macos" | "web"; accordionBorderColor: string;
> accordionContentPadding: number; accordionIconFontSize: number;
> contentStyle: string; ... 180 more ...; Inset: { ...; }; }'.   Type '{
> platformStyle: string; platform: "ios" | "android" | "windows" |
> "macos" | "web"; headerStyle: string; iconStyle: string; contentStyle:
> string; expandedIconStyle: string; accordionBorderColor: string; ...
> 151 more ...; Inset: { ...; }; }' is missing the following properties
> from type '{  platformStyle: any; platform: "ios" | "android"

How do I get rid of this?

inside the native-base-themes folder, there's a material.js file that looks like this:

```
import color from 'color';
import { Platform, Dimensions, PixelRatio } from 'react-native';

import { PLATFORM } from './commonColor';

const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const platform = Platform.OS;
const platformStyle = PLATFORM.MATERIAL;
const isIphoneX =
  platform === PLATFORM.IOS &&
  (deviceHeight === 812 ||
    deviceWidth === 812 ||
    deviceHeight === 896 ||
    deviceWidth === 896);

export default {
  platformStyle,
  platform,

  // Android
  androidRipple: true,
  androidRippleColor: 'rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.3)',
  androidRippleColorDark: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)',
  buttonUppercaseAndroidText: true,
  // Button
  buttonFontFamily: 'Roboto',
  get buttonPrimaryBg() {
    return this.brandPrimary;
  },
  get buttonTextSizeLarge() {
    return this.fontSizeBase * 1.5;
  },

  // Header
  toolbarBtnColor: '#fff',
  toolbarDefaultBg: '#3F51B5',
  toolbarHeight: 56,
  toolbarSearchIconSize: 23,
  toolbarInputColor: '#fff',
  searchBarHeight: platform === PLATFORM.IOS ? 30 : 40,
  searchBarInputHeight: platform === PLATFORM.IOS ? 40 : 50,
  toolbarBtnTextColor: '#fff',
  toolbarDefaultBorder: '#3F51B5',
  iosStatusbar: 'light-content',
  get statusBarColor() {
    return color(this.toolbarDefaultBg)
      .darken(0.2)
      .hex();
  },
  get darkenHeader() {
    return color(this.tabBgColor)
      .darken(0.03)
      .hex();
  },

  // Text
  textColor: '#000',
  inverseTextColor: '#fff',
  noteFontSize: 14,
  get defaultTextColor() {
    return this.textColor;
  },

  // iPhoneX SafeArea
  Inset: {
    portrait: {
      topInset: 24,
      leftInset: 0,
      rightInset: 0,
      bottomInset: 34,
    },
    landscape: {
      topInset: 0,
      leftInset: 44,
      rightInset: 44,
      bottomInset: 21,
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: The error is so verbose that it's cut off before we get to the important part, which is **what are the missing properties?**  I can see that the variable you've provided has 151 more properties whereas the one it's expecting has 180 more so there are probably 29 properties that are missing, but they might not all be required.  Can you post a demo?  Based on what you've provided I don't know what the `getTheme` function is expecting.

Comment: I tried to create a demo on snack expo but since it doesn't have a terminal, I can't run the following command ```node node_modules/native-base/ejectTheme.js```. This is the link that was followed to create this function. Haven't modified anything significant myself https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#theaming-nb-headref @LindaPaiste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To quickly get rid of this, you could simply use `any` type like below:

   `<StyleProvider style={getTheme(commonColor as any)}>`
2. To solve this problem properly, you have to study these two files.

- `native-base-theme/variables/platform.js`
- `native-base-theme/variables/commonColor.js`

The type of the parameter (color) in `getTheme` is inferred from the default export variables in `platform.js`. The error you got means the default export variables in these two files don't match.